# Evothings ble write causing FC

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Everythings's here : https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble/issues/134

I'm trying to send time throung bluetooth to my rpi.
but i can't get `evothings.ble.writeCharacteristic` to work for unknown reason :/

I used writeCharacteristic like this :

app.js

```
ui.append('Time is being updated ...');
device.writeCharacteristic(
    app.SYSTEMINFORMATIONSERVICE,
    characteristic_uuid,
    new Uint8Array([1]),
    function(){
        ui.append('DONE', true);
    },
        function(error){
        ui.append('ERROR', true);
        ui.text('Warning : '+error);
    }
);
```

The app crash just after displaying "Time is being updated ..."

logcat :

```
02-05 11:03:54.416 20011 20011 D BluetoothGatt: readCharacteristic() - uuid: ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-fffffffffff1
02-05 11:03:54.577  1049  1049 E WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 65 num clients 9
02-05 11:03:54.578  1049  1049 E WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=94854 Rx=127944
02-05 11:03:54.670  2185  2206 I bt_btif_gatt: set_read_value unformat.len = 42 
02-05 11:03:54.671 20011 20878 D BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicRead() - Device=B8:27:EB:6C:4F:9C UUID=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-fffffffffff1 Status=0 srvcType=0 srvcInstId=0 charInstId=0
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.evothings.evothingsviewer, PID: 20011
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setWriteType(int)' on a null object reference
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.evothings.BLE$12.run(BLE.java:988)
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-05 11:03:54.694 20011 20011 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

And on serveur side, everything is fine except that OnWriteRequest isn't called. So android app is crashing before sending information.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear and complicated to understand. Try to edit it to ask what you want to know more clearly.

Comment: You're right, just edited.
It now only display the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your logcat, uuid looks strange to me.
 
I don't know what kind of device you are testing with but the uuid is not satisfying its basic format.
Please refer
[Service Discovery in Bluetooth website](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery).

If you are sure about the uuid and how its acquired, please check the characteristic uuid.
It doesn't mean to simply check the string but check how characteristic_uuid is retrieved.
The best way to retrieve it is to call getService then call getCharacteristic.

So for example,

```
var service = evothings.ble.getService(deviceObject, '12345678-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
var characteristic_uuid = evothings.ble.getCharacteristic(service, '11111111-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');

evothings.ble.writeCharacteristic(deviceObject, characteristic_uuid, new Uint8Array([1]), success, error);
```

If these are all good, then please check if the device can receive Uint8Array type.

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks :) - We are trying to build a little ping-pong example with a friend. And we get same error, different phone, different RPi, same crash everytime ... Uuid could be the solution. I'll come back ;)